# Is it possible to perform an event based on coordinates the click occurred at?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to create an app using animation and gestures. So far I've gotten the gestures part and can create the image view and make it move depending on the gesture.

But what I want to do is make a certain image appear based on where the click happened. For example, my entire layout is just a picture of a field. The top 1/4 of the picture is mountains. When someone clicks on that part, I want a flying dog picture to occur and when the click occurs in the field I want a running dog picture to occur. Any advice on how to incorporate coordinates or something?

```
public class FieldActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = FieldActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public TextView mGestureText;
    public ImageView mCorgiFly;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public ImageView mGoldenRun;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_field);

        mGestureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        // Create an object of our Custom Gesture Detector Class
        CustomGestureDetector customGestureDetector = new CustomGestureDetector();
        // Create a GestureDetector
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, customGestureDetector);
        // Attach listeners that'll be called for double-tap and related gestures
        mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(customGestureDetector);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slideshowopenermenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.menu_item_memories:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    class CustomGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            mGestureText.setText("onSingleTapConfirmed");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            mCorgiFly = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.superman);
            mCorgiFly.setImageResource(R.drawable.flyingcorgi);
           // handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             //   @Override
               // public void run() {
                 //   mCorgiFly.setImageDrawable(null);
                //}
            //}, 500);
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
                    0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
            animation.setDuration(1000);  // animation duration
           // animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
            //animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
            //animation.setFillAfter(true);

            mCorgiFly.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            mGestureText.setText("onDoubleTapEvent");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            mGestureText.setText("onDown");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            mGestureText.setText("onShowPress");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            mGestureText.setText("onSingleTapUp");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            mGestureText.setText("onScroll");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            mGestureText.setText("onLongPress");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            mGestureText.setText("onFling " + e1.getX() + " - " + e2.getX());

            if (e1.getX() < e2.getX()) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
            }

            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
            }

            if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
            }

            if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add a touch listener to the imageview, you can then react to different touch inputs (normal long double etc.) and get x/y coordinates.

Comment: @ChristianStengel So the first step is knowing what x/y coordinates I should do the flying and what x/y I do the running right? How do i figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to use a listener and compare the click coordinates wit a desire setpoint, if matches the range then trigger a callback..

Comment: How do i know the coordinates that I should as my range? like at what point do I transition from flying to running?

Comment: are you using a lib for that game?

Comment: Nope. I edited my original question with the code for the activity